# How to get size of set of certain files?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, file-io

For example. I have folder "MyFolder"
And I want to get the size of all files that file name is "`*D.*`"

Is there a easy way to do this?

(P.S. I know for whole folder, I can use TotalSize() to get its size, but how about with my constraints?)

Comment: Can you clarify? There can't be more than one file within a folder that has a given name, so I'm assuming you mean that the name matches some sort of pattern.

Comment: Always say which version of .NET you're using.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: he didn't quote his `*`. Look again.

Comment: .TotalSize()..? what function is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a easy way to do this?

Yes, there is. A single line of code actually:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long size = Directory
            .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\work", "*d.*")
            .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
            .Sum(x => x.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(@"The size of files in c:\work\*d.* is {0} bytes", size);
    }
}
```

And if you are targeting a .NET version prior to .NET 4.0 where the [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx) method is not available you could use the [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) method instead.

Comment: You could use the overload of EnumerateFiles that takes a pattern to remove the need for the `.Where(...)`.

Comment: I think the pattern in the question may have been changed since you read it - it has two wildcards and a period in it. Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: @Weeble, pattern updated in my answer to match the pattern in the question.

Comment: @opatachibueze, sure, this has been reflected in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there's any easy way around creating the sum yourself. There are different approaches, e.g.:

```
DirectoryInfo mydir = new DirectoryInfo();
long size = 0;
foreach(FileInfo file in mydir.GetFiles("D*"))
    size += file.Length();
```

Comment: Directory.GetFiles returns string[] type

Comment: No, it returns `FileInfo[]` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx ) Note that I'm using `DirectoryInfo`- not `Directory`.